# SQL Full Text Search - Design Decision: Multiple Tables or One Huge One

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm somewhat new to SQL but I'm creating a database where there's one table of movie metadata, and I need to do full text searches on the movie scripts, which are currently organized into large tables, one for each movie, with columns for line number, timestamp, and a body of text (which needs to be able to be searched for keywords, phrases). My question is whether my searches would run faster using one massive table for all of the scripts instead of one for each movie. I'm using SQLite and Python. I'm using fts4 to implement the full text search capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Having each movie into a separate table is not a architecture easy to maintain, as you have to add/delete tables when a new movie is inserted of removed.

Searching in a massive table can be efficient only with indexes with a good clustering factor.

Generally as I see the whole problem I think that the adaptation of a documentation based database like [mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) will provide better storage and search of your data.